# Twitter bootstrap navbar class affects text alignment

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, text-alignment

First example aligns as expected.  Second (navbar class) does not:

```
<div>
  <span>Good</span>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">logout</button>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <span>Bad</span>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">logout</button>
</div>
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y76Nt/1/

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What browser? It looks fine in Firefox/Win7: http://jsfiddle.net/YsMhP 

I did close the input tags and remove orphan li and a tags. Not sure if that's a factor in your browser.

Comment: @isherwood - Thanks for the fiddle and good catch.  I have since edited the post with a reduced test case.  Using Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in the docs.  Just escaped me earlier:

Text:
Wrap strings of text in an element with .navbar-text, usually on a `<p>` tag for proper leading and color.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar